# Xamarin designer tools like WPF in BLEND or VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

Is there a tool that has a design mode to select the graphic components and see the code of this element.
And also have the structure of the document?

With visual studio, there is just the preview, which does not work when using third-party components like "FFImageLoading"

The best way I found is to start my project in debug mode and make the XAML changes. But it is much less practical than the designer of WPF

With WPF designer
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the world of meager tooling in Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research the best is to design its interface in debug mode, the changes are done live when you save the view with hot-reload which is integrated into visual studio 2019. I do not understand what is the purpose of extensions like gorilla or liveXaml, because they do nothing else.

The only interesting extension is the one used to format XAML, the formatting is perfect and is done automatically with saved : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TeamXavalon.XAMLStyler